# Python using re.compile html to set website update alert

Tags: python, html, python-re

I would like to set an alert if the website has any update.
Seems I need to use re.compile to set regular expression, but I am not familiar with that, I use:

```
def Request():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36'}     
    req = requests.get('https://xueqiu.com/u/4357540281', headers=headers)   
    content = req.content    
    pattern = re.compile('.html').findall(content) #how
    return pattern 

def update():
    print('In progress')
    old_pattern = Request() 
    while True:
        new_pattern = Request() 
        if (new_pattern!= old_pattern):  
            old_pattern=new_pattern    
            send_email()  
        else:
            now=datetime.datetime.now()
            print(now,"No Update")
        time.sleep(300)
            
            
def send_email():
```

Any help will be highly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: see that reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-script-to-monitor-website-changes/

Comment: In fact, you don't need hashlib or re, you can just compare the whole website: `old.content == current.content`

Comment: @Programmer Hi, thanks for your help, but if I delete ```pattern```, it returns a connection error

Comment: Sorry, works fin on my machine, see my example

Comment: Next time post the error message the first time directly, please ... This error says that 1) `xueqiu.com`'s server is busy 2) Your internet connection is too slow 3) something else with your internet connection is wrong. Can you access websites from your browser ?

Comment: Why do you have all common browsers set in `UserAgent`, by the way ? One should be enough ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to do this, or, as  @DavidMeu siggested, hashlib. Just check if `old_request.content != new_req.content`:

```py
def get_content():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36'}     
    req = requests.get('https://xueqiu.com/u/4357540281', headers=headers)   
    return req.content

def update():
    print('In progress')
    old_content = get_content() 
    while True:
        new_content = Request() 
        if old_content != new_content):  
            old_content = new_content   
            send_email()  
        else:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(now, "No Update")
        time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but it keeps return ```[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond``` error on my side, no idea why